# PHP. Function that returns form post

Tags: php, forms

Below is a sample of my function

```
function form ($data){
'<form action="url.php" method="POST">
<!-- Input fields -->
</form>';
return  //submit the form;
}
```

When the above function is called the form data gets encrypted and posted. The idea is to hide the form data altogether and post it as an encrypted value when being submitted.

I am looking for a way to programmatically execute the POST method within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the POST url, the you can use curl like below example:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <!-- Other input -->
    <button name="submit">
        Send Data!
    </button>
</form>
```

Here's the PHP with cURL:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $var = $_POST["input_name"];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/url.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "postvar1=" . $var);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch); //Here's are the reponse (Maybe JSON or text base)

    curl_close ($ch);

    if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }
}
```

These above example works for sending POST Request internally (on server-side) so public cannot view the POST URL. You might also encrypt the `$var` before the `curl_exec();`